# Handlebars disable attribute if id exist

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I have list of electoralUnits and I need to disable some in that list if that id of electoralUnit is added in other collection called StateResult.

Route:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    StateResult.find({})
      .then(stateResults => {
        ElectoralUnit.find({})
          .then(electoralUnits => {
            StateList.find({})
              .then(stateLists => {
                res.render('home/results/stateResults', {
                  stateResults: stateResults,
                  electoralUnits: electoralUnits,
                  stateLists: stateLists
            });
          });
       });
    });
});
```

Now, I tried this in handlebars with if helper:

```
<select name="electoralUnit" multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" size="40">
  {{#each electoralUnits}}
      <option value="{{id}}" {{#each stateResults}} {{#if this}} disabled {{/if}} {{/each}}>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

and a lot of variations of this, like:

```
<option value="{{id}}" {{#each stateResults}} {{#if electoralUnit}} disabled {{/if}} {{/each}}>{{name}}</option>
```

but nothing works. Where am I wrong?

This is data from mongodb:
electoralunits collection

```
{"_id":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592591","town":"5ab903952e9dc70408a81e32","name":"1. МЗ Аеродром - Дом Здравља","__v":0,"electoralNumber":4200,"safeVoter":360,"date":"2018-04-25T15:19:37.900Z"}
```

stateresults collection

```
{"_id":"5ac4e01d46fa2b21280bd981","electoralUnit":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592591","allVotes":100,"validVotes":90,"invalidVotes":10,"partyVotes":[50,10,10,10,5,5],"__v":0}
```

I tried as @doowb explain me with custom handlebars helper:

```
includes: function(arr, prop, val, options) {

        const matches = arr.map(item => item[prop]).includes(val);
        if (matches) {
          return options.fn(this);
        } else {
          return options.inverse(this);
        }

    }

<select name="electoralUnit" multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" size="40">
  {{#each electoralUnits}}
      <option value="{{this._id}}" {{#includes ../stateResults "electoralUnit" this._id}} hidden {{/includes}}>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

but this won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you show that the `stateResults`, `electoralUnits`, and `stateLists` objects look like, but I think your issue is with knowing which "depth" you're currently trying to access data from. In the express middleware you're passing all of those objects to the template at the root of the object:

```
{
  stateResults: [], // assuming this is an array
  electoralUnits: [], // assuming this is an array
  stateLists: [] // assuming this is an array
}
```

In the `{{#each stateResults}}` you'll need to use the parent specifier: `{{#each ../stateResults}}` since the first `{{#each}}` block created a new depth. Also, the logic of the data objects doesn't seem correct since you don't need to add multiple `disabled` attributes to the `option` tag. If you post what the actual data objects look like, I'll edit this answer with additional information.

Edit: After getting more information, I think that using the [`{{pluck}}`](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#pluck) and [`{{inArray}}`](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#inarray) helpers and subexpressions like the following will achieve your goal. If the `../stateResults` does work, then try `@root.stateResults` (I'm still assuming that the collections returned are arrays of those mongodb objects):

```
<select name="electoralUnit" multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" size="40">
  {{#each electoralUnits}}
      <option value="{{this._id}}" {{#inArray (pluck ../stateResults "electoralUnit") this._id}} disabled {{/inArray}}>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

If you don't want to use the `handlebars-helpers` library (indicated in a comment below) you can create your own helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('includes', function(arr, prop, val, options) {
  const matches = arr.map(item => item[prop]).includes(val);
  if (matches) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Then you can use that helper like this:

```
<select name="electoralUnit" multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" size="40">
  {{#each electoralUnits}}
      <option value="{{this._id}}" {{#includes ../stateResults "electoralUnit" this._id}} disabled {{/includes}}>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: I added data in question. As you see, since voterturnouts has electoralunit object id then in #each loop that should be disabled. I tried {{#each ../stateResults}} but nothing change with that.

Comment: I meant to add stateresults, sorry, I edited one more time. But, it is similar because both has electoralunits as objectId in it. Now you can see stateresults.

Comment: Also, is the goal to disable an option if the `electoralunit` in `stateResults` is the same as the `_id` in the `electoralunit`?

Comment: The goal is to disable in multiple select only electoralunits that appear with _id in stateresults. In that page I have a lot input fields, electoralunit is one of them, and when id of electoralunits is found in stateresults then is no more need to select that field, that's way I need to disable it.

Comment: I edited the answer with what I think will work (this will require using `handlebars-helpers`, which I think you are since that's where you asked before :) )

Comment: I only install express-handlebars and add functions manualy to separate js file. I have not install handlebars-helpers. Can I just add function for pluck helper?

Comment: I added another alternative.

Comment: There's nothing at that link. I'm not sure how to debug your issue... you could look at the html that's generated to see if it's working or use the `{{log .}}` helper in different places to see if you're data looks the way you think it should (this will do `console.log` where your express server is running).

Comment: I don't know why hastebin not working, sorry for broken link. I edited first question with your code as example. I output includes from handlebars-helpers.js so I don't know why is not working. I will try to console.log as I try in the past but I have a less and less idea :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170321/discussion-between-nenad-m-and-doowb).

Comment: I console.log(matches) and found out that displays false for 12 times because It has 3 electoralUnit ObjectId inside stateResult and 15 in electoralUnits collection so 12 are missing. I believe that mean something to you?

Comment: That seems correct since you're only trying to disable electoral units if they already have state results... I'm assuming that not all of them would be true until all of the electoral units have state results. I'm not sure what else I can help with. If you're still having trouble, maybe you should reduce the data down to something that you can more easily work with and try that (without having to use the database).

Comment: I still have trouble. I upload project to github repositorie https://github.com/shone83/CRMElectors so, when you have time, you can see if I use your code properly.